# Вызвать функции из dll

Tags: java, c++

Можно ли из `java` кода вызвать **готовые** функции из `dll`, написанного на `C++`, а не писать `dll` изначально под `java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этого есть [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) (Java Native Interface). 
В сети масса примеров, как это сделать. Например вот: http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/

Comment: В интерфейсе надо указывать все методы из `dll` или только нужные?

Comment: Все необязательно, только нужные. У меня небольшой опыт работы с JNI, я как-то использовал некоторые функции WinAPI и я точно брал только те, которые понадобились